# Whenever i use incense to attract pokemon it shows "Failed TO Detect Location"?

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever i use incense to attract pokemon it shows "Failed TO Detect Location"?
However the Game runs without any errror whenever i try to use Incense this damn happens.I Also cannot find any Pokemon even after Walking 300 meter?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your GPS is not working or undetected, you will not be able to play at all. The game often bugs for me, you can try to kill and restart it.

To find pokemons, if you are lucky, you can find a place with lot of them without moving, but most of the time you'll must walk several miles to find them. I think the best place to find some is in a park for example with lots of pokestop or arena (it attracts them). 
Latter you will be able to add a bait on a pokestop to attract them much more.

Good luck :)

Comment: GPS perfectly works in google maps ...My friends find Pokemon within 50m of range

Comment: Morever i play from India where it is yet to be launched

Answer (score 0):

According to this website : http://www.techradar.com/how-to/gaming/how-to-fix-pokemon-go-problems-1325007

> If Lure Modules or Incense don't work and start attracting Pokémon a trick has been found that could fix this Pokémon Go problem.
>
> To fix it, try switching your smartphone's time to the network time. This is the time that your mobile network sets, and it seems to be helping people fix their Lure and Incense problems.

Try it out and see if it works, personally since I haven't used any incense yet I haven't encountered any problems so I cannot vouch for this method, good luck..